# Need JS equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, hmac

Python Code:

```
signature = hmac.new(bytearray.fromhex(key), data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Solutions That I have tried

```
var compute_hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(data).digest('hex');

var compute_hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'hex').toString()).update(data).digest('hex');
```

`const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256',   Buffer.from(key, 'hex'))`

Trying to validate webhook signatures of the following API

`https://developer.close.com/topics/webhooks/`

**data** is the payload received, the same thing is passed to python and JS code. But somehow, hex digest of python code is validated and hex code of JS code is entirely different.

Please refer to API link mentioned above (webhook signatures) to understand what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What is `data`? What results did you get?

Comment: *"Solutions That I have tried"* **Thank you** for including those, people often don't. But what is `data`? And what problem did you have with your solutions?

Comment: I'm getting different signatures, data passed to python code and js code is exactly same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass directly the keybuffer instead of adding .toString() to it

```
var compute_hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'hex')).update(data).digest('hex');
```

py code

```
import hashlib
import hmac

key ="A1FF92";
data = "hello"

signature = hmac.new(bytearray.fromhex(key), data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
//78a1151ddd4f298a134e4625362af2ab8ef4bd49719e17053ec1eadd4cbf1bab
```

node code

```
var crypto = require("crypto")
var key = "A1FF92"
var data="hello";
var compute_hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'hex')).update(data).digest('hex');

// 78a1151ddd4f298a134e4625362af2ab8ef4bd49719e17053ec1eadd4cbf1bab
```